# Ошибка компиляции .net6 teamcity

Tags: c#, teamcity

Я пытаюсь скомпельровать проэкт на TeamCity server и получаю следующую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я предполагаю, что TeamCity server не поддерживает в моем случае с# 6 объекты. Как можно устранить эту ошибку?

Comment: прошу отредактируйте вопрос и приложите код, а не картинку. также приложите параметры вашего агента (в настройках агента на тимсити видно)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/64wh5743.aspx

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что типы `Func<>` в .NET 3.5 [располагались](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.90).aspx) в сборке `System.Core`. А с .NET 4.0 они [переехали](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.100).aspx) в `mscorlib`.

Как видно из лога ТимСити, у вас одновременно подключены `System.Core` версии 3.5.0.0 и `mscorlib` версии 4.0.0.0. Проблема может быть решена в любую сторону: либо обе сборки должны быть версии 3.5, либо 4.0.